# Print freeform text in a Perl function?

Tags: perl, indentation, heredoc

I have been getting a very odd error when trying to print freeform text in a subroutine in Perl. Below is the code I am calling

```
    print OUTFILE <<"HEADER";
The freeform text would go here
HEADER
```

The odd thing is that this only works in the main of my function. As soon as I place it in a function call, I get this error:

```
Can't find string terminator "HEADER" anywhere before EOF
```

Meaning it can't find the HEADER, even though it is there. Can you not use freeform text within a function (subroutine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that there is no space/tab/indentation before ending string identifier, that is `HEADER`. Your code should look like this:

```
        function someFunc(){
          print OUTFILE <<"HEADER";
      The freeform text would go here
HEADER
        }
```

Notice that there is no space/tab/indentation before `HEADER` there. It should start from first character of its line.

**Check this tutorial out for more information:**

- [Perl Here-Doc Tutorial](http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/qt/perlheredoc.htm)

**Quoting:**

> The important rule to remember is that
>   you finish a here-doc using the same
>   word you started, and it must be by
>   itself on the line

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. A tab-HEADER is not the same thing as HEADER. It just so happened that without the function call none of the lines were indented.

Comment: Be careful: if you indent the text, that leading whitespace is included. There are many ways around this, some of them quite slick and convenient, but you do have to be aware of this.

Comment: @tchrist: That's true, there should be no whitespace surrounding it.